# Using multiple roots directories to access the same project with NGINX

Tags: nginx

So I've got this NGINX config

```
server{
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name cerdman.me;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
server {

    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443;
    server_name cerdman.me;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/cerdman.me/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/cerdman.me/privkey.pem;

    root /home/ubuntu/portfolio/resume/; #show users the resume by default


    index index.html;

    # Other config you desire (TLS, logging, etc)...

        location /resume/ {
            root /home/ubuntu/portfolio; 
            index index.html;
    }
    location /weatherapp/ { 
            root /home/ubuntu/portfolio;
                index index.html;
    }
}
```

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve here is to have my resume be served by default if someone goes to https://cerdman.me. I'm having trouble doing this in a way that doesn't interfere with my other project(s).

My second project, at /weatherapp/ was created using create-react-app. As is, my app will try to access resources from several urls, lets take the example `https://cerdman.me/static/js/2.70e4302a.chunk.js`. When this url request is sent to my server, the server doesn't have a location block for it, so it tries to use the server's root directory. In the end it looks in `/home/ubuntu/portfolio/resume/static/js/2.70e4302a.chunk.js` instead of `/home/ubuntu/portfolio/weatherapp/static/js/2.70e4302a.chunk.js` where the files actually are.

What I need to do is somehow to redirect these resource requests being made by the weatherapp project such that I can maintain my current file structure, or to find an alternative structure that circumvents the problem entirely while still being scalable. Maybe putting both projects into one server isn't the right way?

Comment: You could leave the `/resume/` where it is and send visitors to `/` there instead. For example: `location = / { return 302 /resume/; }`

Comment: I have tried something similar. I can't do the redirect at the server level because then everything gets redirected. Doing it at  location / would solve the problem but then clients have to navigate to https://cerdman.me with forward slash instead of just https://cerdman.me. I supposed location / is meant to represent the root entire project, so it doesn't make sense.

Comment: `example.com` and `example.com/` is the same URL, it's just the browser's address bar chooses not to show the `/` when it's the root URI.

Comment: Really? That's interesting. Well if that's the case then I guess it doesn't matter and my problem is trivial. I'll give that a shot.

Comment: So, after making these changes, things still aren't quite working. The problem now is that the js and css requests get routed to /resume/ now. I don't quite understand why though.